# Animation not working in matplotlib python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib-animation

I am doing my first matplotlib animation graph. and It's not working.please someone explain me,why??

```py
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

n = 100
X = np.random.randn(n)

def update(curr):
    if curr == n:
        a.event_source.stop()
    plt.cla()
    bins = np.arange(-4,4, 0.5)
    plt.hist(X[:curr], bin=bins)
    plt.axis([-4,4,0,30])
    plt.annotate("n={}".format(curr),(3,27))
  

fig = plt.figure()
a = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=100)
```

P.S. I am coding on jupyter notebook

Comment: have you tried `plt.show()`?

Comment: yes. tried and not working.

Comment: can you please give reproducible code full? the `curr` variable is not recognized.

Comment: Actually, I am doing a coursera course on data visualization in that the prof told, corr is a recursive variable which will automatically update after each time function runs.

Comment: Oh, I see. I would suggest you ask this on the coursera forum then.

Answer (score 1):

I got my answer. It's a typo in plt.hist call. The parameter is `bins` not `bin`.
`plt.hist(X[:curr], bins=bins)`